# PHP check for words within a string without a foreach loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I have the following code:

```
$wordsArray = ...
foreach ( $wordsArray as $word ) 

    if ( strpos( $string, $word ) !== FALSE ) { 
         echo "Word found! Handle this a certain way" }
    }
    
}
```

Unfortunately, with such a large array of words (probably close to 100), the loop is too slow especially when I am passing in thousands of strings to this function, and running this foreach loop thousands of times.  How can I speed this process up, or restructure my code that way I do not need to loop through my array of words, but rather make use of the string itself and check whether any substring of it is found within my array?  I need to make this part of my code more efficient.

Also, what makes this more difficult is that each string has no whitespaces.  Instead, take the following example:

> Passed String: "Hereissomerandomsentence"
>
> Array of Words: ('some', 'are', 'the');

My script would return Word Found because of the "some," but I want to find a faster way to do this.

Comment: "do not need to loop through my array of words, but rather make use of the string itself and check whether any substring of it is found within my array" --- why do you think that `2 + 3` is faster than `3 + 2`?

Comment: The sad truth is that using a foreach and in_array is faster than using array_walk with declared or anonymous functions. What exactly are you doing? trying to find bad words?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about improving working code, and may be more suitable for http://CodeReview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Yeah, I see.  I am doing something similar to that (instead scanning each line of source code for a large number of webpages, and then identifying flaws in code based on what's contained within my array).

Comment: A regex ala `/foo|bar|.../` is easily generated from an array list.

Comment: @mario I was thinking of something like that! Can you explain more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy but also not easy. Here is some code which uses [`preg_match_all`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) and simple regex as an example:

```
// Set the string.
$string = 'Hereissomerandomsentence';

// Set the words array.
$wordsArray = array('some', 'are', 'the');

// Set the regex pattern.
$regex_pattern = '/(?:' . implode('|', $wordsArray) . ')/i';

// Run a regex to get the value between the link tags.
preg_match_all($regex_pattern, $string, $matches);

// Return the results.
echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches);
echo '</pre>';
```

And here are the results:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => some
        )

)
```

But when I say this is not easy, the lack of spaces might result in `then` being matched to `the` and such. Remember, computers can’t read. It’s all pattern logic. So if I add `then` and `are` to the example string like this:

```
// Set the string.
$string = 'Hereissomerandomsentencethenhereweare';
```

The results reflect the `the` in `then` being picked up:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => some
            [1] => the
            [2] => are
        )

)
```

**EDIT:** The original poster asks a fair—but complicated—question in the comments:

> What if I only want a word preceded by another certain word? For
>   example, using this same test string, how could you change the regex
>   only to include `some` when preceded by `is`, `the` when preceded by
>   `then`, and `are` when preceded by 'we'? So for your example, the
>   output would only be 'some' and `are`.

What you are asking to do is complicated, but doable using “Lookarounds” [as explained on this site](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#lookaround):

Here is a sample using the above code:

```
$string = 'Hereissomerandomsentencethenhereweare';

// Set the regex pattern.
$regex_pattern = '/(?<=is)some|(?<=then)the|(?<=we)are/i';

// Run a regex to get the value between the link tags.
preg_match_all($regex_pattern, $string, $matches);

// Return the results.
echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches);
echo '</pre>';
```

And the results would be as you expect it:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => some
            [1] => are
        )

)
```

And here is an explanation of that regex `/(?<=is)some|(?<=then)the|(?<=we)are/i`:

- The slashes (`/`) at the beginning and end are just delimiters.
- The `|` character is simply and `OR` between conditions.
- Now what is in between the `OR` conditions are patterns.

Now let’s use the first `(?<=is)some` as an example.

- The `(?<=[word in here])` is a “Lookbehind” which means: Only capture the words that follow this if they are preceded by the word in here. And in the word in this case is `is`.
- And the word that follows is `some`.
- So it all adds to to: Only match `some` if preceded by `is`. Then `the` only if preceded by `then`. Then `are` only if preceded by `we`.

Now knowing that there is a pattern here could could probably create a multi-dimensional array that can set logic for words to only be checked if preceded by another word. And then loop though that to create a pile of regex. But that is a big task.

But at least now you know the basics of regex for this task!

Comment: But the issue here is performance, not the quality of the code in and of its self. Can you provide some benchmarking here?

Comment: That's pretty cool!  But why is it outputting each array of matches twice?  I'm a little confused by that.  Thanks for this! @JakeGould

Comment: Yeah, I did that.  This is pretty awesome.  I am going to test the timing right now. @JakeGould

Comment: @JakeGould One other thing before I check the answer, what if I only want a word preceded by another certain word?  For example, using this same test string, how could you change the regex only to include 'some' when preceded by 'is', 'the' when preceded by 'then', and 'are' when preceded by 'we'?  So for your example, the output would only be 'some' and 'are'.  I know this is weird but I am trying to figure out this regex.

Comment: @JakeGould I know what I am trying to do above is probably really complicated, because we can't just hard-code those array words into the regex… hmmm

Comment: The array of matches is output twice, because you're using capturing parentheses; use `(?: ... )` to avoid that.

Answer (score 2):

There will be some loops involved, whether you like it or not, though some optimisation might be possible when you switch to regular expressions instead:

```
$re = '/(?:' . join('|', array_map(function($word) {
    return preg_quote($word, '/');
}, $wordsArray)) . ')/';

if (preg_match_all($re, $string, $matches)) {
    // hurray!
    print_r($matches[0]);
}
```

Comment: @JakeGould Somehow I understood the exact opposite of that :) updated.

Answer (score 1):

- Sort the array that holds the potential subordinate words that could
  be found in $string.
- Consider a multidimensional array organized by starting letter; make a dictionary of potential matches instead of using a massive, unsorted array.
- Parse a copy of $string by cutting it into individual characters.
- Know what characters can be found at what index.
- Put those characters into a set, so that you only use the unique
  characters.
- Examine each of those unique characters. If a subordinate word in the
  array does not begin with one of those unique characters, or hold
  those characters, then it can be discarded as a potential match.

Using ideas like these, you could cut down on the number of comparisons required.  By decreasing the size of the potential solution set, you might be able to speed up the matching.

In order for these reduction techniques to show their worth, the array of potential matches will need to be large.  That is, the processing time you save will need to be outweighed by the processing time spent on cutting out the unlikely matches.

In the sample string provided, the alphabet was used like this:
a 2
b
c 1 
d 1
e 11
f
g
h 3
i 1
j
k
l
m 2
n 4
o 2
p
q
r 4
s 3
t 2
u
v
w 1
x
y
z.

So, 13 letters of 26 were not used at all.  Half of the letters did not occur.  Also, e occurred almost 3 times as much as its closer competitors: h, n and r.  This implies that eliminating subordinate words by how they start might cut down on time.